# Ora-00932 - expected NUMBER got -

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have been running the below query without issue:

```
with Nums (NN) as
(
select 0 as NN
from dual
union all
select NN+1 -- (1)
from Nums
where NN < 30
)

select null as errormsg, trunc(sysdate)-NN as the_date, count(id) as the_count
from Nums
left join
(
    SELECT c1.id,  trunc(c1.c_date)   as c_date
    FROM table1 c1
    where c1.c_date > trunc(sysdate) - 30
    UNION
    SELECT c2.id, trunc(c2.c_date)
    FROM table2 c2
    where c2.c_date > trunc(sysdate) -30
) x1
on x1.c_date =  trunc(sysdate)-Nums.NN
group by trunc(sysdate)-Nums.NN
```

However, when I try to pop this in a proc for SSRS use:

```
procedure pr_do_the_thing (RefCur out sys_refcursor)

is 
  oops  varchar2(100);
begin

open RefCur for
-- see above query --
;
end pr_do_the_thing;
```

I get

> Error(): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got -

Any thoughts? Like I said above, as a query, there is no issue. As a proc, the error appears at note (1) int eh query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be bug 18139621 (see MOS Doc ID 2003626.1). There is a patch available, but if this is the only place you encounter this, it might be simpler to switch to a hierarchical query:

```
with Nums (NN) as
(
    select level - 1
    from dual
    connect by level <= 31
)
...
```

---

You could also calculate the dates inside the CTE (which also fails with a recursive CTE):

```
with Dates (DD) as
(
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1
    from dual
    connect by level <= 31
)
select null as errormsg, DD as the_date, count(id) as the_count
from Dates
left join
(
    SELECT c1.id,  trunc(c1.c_date)   as c_date
    FROM table1 c1
    where c1.c_date > trunc(sysdate) - 30
    UNION
    SELECT c2.id, trunc(c2.c_date)
    FROM table2 c2
    where c2.c_date > trunc(sysdate) -30
) x1
on x1.c_date = DD
group by DD;
```

I'd probably organise it slightly differently, so the subquery doesn't limit the date range directly:

```
with dates (dd) as
(
    select trunc(sysdate) - level + 1
    from dual
    connect by level <= 31
) 
select errormsg, the_date, count(id) as the_count
from (
    select null as errormsg, d.dd as the_date, c1.id
    from dates d
    left join table1 c1 on c1.c_date >= d.dd and c1.c_date < d.dd + 1
    union all
    select null as errormsg, d.dd as the_date, c2.id
    from dates d
    left join table2 c2 on c2.c_date >= d.dd and c2.c_date < d.dd + 1
)
group by errormsg, the_date;
```

but as always with these things, check the performance of each approach...

Also notice that I've switched from `union` to `union all`. If an ID could appear more than once on the same day, in the same table or across both tables, then the counts will be different - you need to decide whether you want to count them once or as many times as they appear. That applies to your original query too.